# Pros and cons of having a Ph.D. advisor who is (possibly) younger than me

Tags: phd, advisor, age

I applied for a Ph.D. position.

A new assistant professor who would join that university next year reached me and asked whether I wanted to work with him. I have been working for two years since my Master graduation. I think his direction suits my interest.

He began his Ph.D. right after undergraduate study so I guess he is probably at my age, 27 or 28, even younger. If we are both 40s, I might be ok with that.

Comment: Are you looking for someone to tell you how to feel, or...?

Comment: No, I just ask others how to feel. I feel exactly what I am feeling.

Comment: Right now the question is too broad and will generate opinion based answers. Better would be to ask if some of the concerns you have are valid.

Comment: What are you worried about exactly?

Comment: Swallow your pride. There is always someone much better than you at something and that's okay because it gives you opportunity to learn. If you would rather work with another professor for a legitimate reason then do that. But don't bite the hand that feeds you.

Comment: Your question is unclear - you mention “he is at my age, 27 or 28” then you say you are in your 40’s ... Teachers come across students of all abilities including those who are smarter in particular areas ... they still help them.

Comment: @neuranna Your edit introduce two problems. (1) As Solar Mike pointed out, what is the OP's age? The OP never said he is in his 40's in his original post. (2) The current version changes the merits of the original question. I understand your intention was to make it less opinion based. But, this edit brought in some confusion. To the OP, please look at the edit and do some edits if needed.

Comment: @SolarMike I roll back part of the original post. Hope this would make things a little bit clearer. To the OP, please look at the current version. Please edit it if it is not what you want to ask. Thanks.

Comment: There is no question.

Comment: @Mark There was a question in the original post. Someone edited it out. Now, it becomes no question. I did not want to start an edit war, so I just brought part of the original post back. Hopefully the OP will edit his post to make it clear when he comes back.

Answer (score 8):

As you get older, it is basically dead certain that you will at some point be reporting to someone who is much younger than you are.  Think about why that has to be true.  If you're still stuck, ask yourself how old you think your supervisor will be when you're in your 60s.  You need to get over it.

Answer (score 8):

There is a Chinese proverb

> 學無前後，達者為先

One of the English translations I like is from [the page](https://forum.hkej.com/node/106964)

> In Learning, there's no first or last;
>
> When one learns and progresses fast,
>
> Then the last shall become the first --
>
> She would be my Teacher at last.

And another translation from [the page](http://blog.chinadaily.com.cn/thread-36998-1-1.html)

> In learning there’s no first or last, but whoever becomes enlightened and understands relevant subjects first is the frontrunner in the field. (Paul D. Young)

Answer (score 2):

I think the research interests and experience of a supervisor is more important than their age (and sex, race, etc).